# What does %2 specify in where clause on the left of operator?

Tags: sql-server

What does %2 signify in where clause on the left of operator?

```
SELECT Customer.custid, Customer.companyname, 
 [Order].orderid, [Order].orderdate
FROM Sales.Customers AS Customer
 INNER JOIN Sales.Orders AS [Order]
  ON Customer.custid = [Order].custid
WHERE Customer.custid <= 2 AND [Order].orderid %2 = 0
```

I observed that results are exactly half if I ignore the order condition completely in my sample database. adding pic of side by side compression I see.

[image]

Comment: `[Order].orderid %2 = 0` will only return records where `orderid` is even. `%` here means all those order id's which give a remainder of 0 when divided by 2 (i.e. even numbers).

Comment: They're not the same results. One of them returns 5 rows, the other 10. You can't see the difference? Even with the lines numbered?

Comment: I see so it is a computation in the where clause. it makes sense now but why would anyone want to do that with orders?

Comment: Thanks @AmitSukralia. you have answered my question.

Comment: In SQL Server `%` is the **modulus** operator, more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)